# What does 御用人 mean?

Tags: kanji

I've been wanting to read  神様の御用人 but I can't figure out what  御用人 means. Some translations translate it to "friend" but I think there's a deeper meaning to it?

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%BA-269938#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

御用人 is 御用+人, 御用 meaning "at the service of" and 人 meaning person. It means that some character(s) are dedicated servants of some god(s).

Comment: @TheAvianLord How is this the best answer?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the meaning is that deep. 御 is just an honorific, and 用人 is a sort of an old word meaning retainer, servant or manager. In the context of the story I think it refers to the main character having that as a job or something, probably meaning God's servant, so I don't think 'friend' is that close of a translation.

EDIT: Avery's answer is correct, not mine

Comment: `Avery's answer is correct, not mine` <- What makes you think so? You looked up [用人]{ようにん} in a dictionary, right? http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226710/meaning/m0u/

Comment: i did, but I'm not sure the dictionary definition applies in this case because I cross-referenced the wikipedia page for the series he is talking about and the main character's job is closer to what Avery said

Comment: Heh.. but the dictionary clearly states that 御用人 is the honorific form of 用人, you see https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%BA-269938#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88　Also Wiki says: "用人（ようにん）は、江戸時代の武家の職制のひとつで、主君の用向きを家中に伝達して、庶務を司ることを主たる役目とし、有能な者から選ばれることが多かった。 **御用人（ごようにん）とも。** " https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%BA

Comment: That's probably not how the word was constructed, @Schokolade , based on how 御用 is used in modern Japanese. I do not know whether the series takes place in Edo, I didn't google it

Comment: 「御用」を聞く「人」、だから「御用」+「人」？この作品の題名に限って、「御用+人」っていう、著者が新しく作った coined word？

Comment: @Schokolade doesn't that kind of thing often happen with light novels and anime?

Comment: I think it might be a coined word and the anime/novel is set in modern times so I don't know if they would use an Edo-era word